Electron window is 1px smaller on Linux
I was creating an Electron window on Linux on a 1920x1080 display but resulting viewport is 1px smaller (1919x1079). Window created like this:
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('node:path')

function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    frame: false,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  mainWindow.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 1920, height: 1080 })

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  mainWindow.show()
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})


What options should be used to have viewport 1920x1080?

Presumably the window manager border accounts for some of that difference?

There is no border. Just an empty space behind.

Window needs to be created like this:
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    resizable: false,  // <----- This options enables Electron window to take all space
    frame: false,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

Electron documentation on resizable option.
